# Custom Layout for a specific router not displaying in Meteor with Iron Router

Tags: layout, meteor, iron-router

I want to use a different layout template for pages such as login, 404, and other pages. However, when calling this template in my route (using Iron Router), it appears to be ignored and instead uses the default template. How can I update this so that it uses the intended layout?

**This is the custom layout I want to use**

```
<template name="UtilityLayout">
  <div class="ui centered grid">
    <div class="six wide column">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>
```

**My general Iron Router Config:**

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'AppLayout',
  loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'NotFoundLayout'
});
```

**This is the before hook where I am calling the route**

```
    Router.onBeforeAction(function () {

     //redirect to /login if a user is not signed and if they are not already on login (to prevent a redirect loop)
      if (!Meteor.userId() && (Router.current().route.getName() !== 'login')) {
        this.redirect('login');
        // I also tried Router.go('login');
      } else {
        this.next();
      }
    });
```

**This is the route where I am referencing the custom layout (that appears to be ignored):**

```
    Router.route('/login', { name: 'login'}, function(){
       this.layout('UtilityLayout');
    });
```

Comment: You can define a `route controller` which I believe should override the global `Router.configure` parameters. https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-controllers and https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/281